# Plugin:Read More Right Here , How to change the name (more...) to Read More

Tags: plugins, read-more

Hi all I am using [Read More Right Here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/read-more-right-here/) Plugin when i using the `<!--more-->` Tag 
it appears like `(more...)` I need to know how to change the `(more...)` to Read More`

Anyone Much appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried the basic ["customizing the more link"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) stuff? This may not have anything to do with the plugin.

Comment: I believe that there is an option on the plugin settings page that will let you do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your functions.php file:

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
        return 'Read More';
    }
    add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```